# How to make vim interpret escaped characters as colors

Tags: vim, vimrc

I'm using [zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap) logging for an application and I've noticed that when I open the log using `tail` the colors resolve as expected but when using vim I get a bunch of entries that look like the following:

```
^[[34mINFO^[[0m
```

I tried installing https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4979 but it didn't seem to solve it.

Comment: It appears that script is not meant to me installed as a module / plugin, but rather `source`d once a file with ANSI control codes is already open in the buffer.

Comment: @DopeGhoti how do i source it once the file is open?

Comment: `:source /path/to/script.vim`

Answer (score 1):

You've found a fork of the *AnsiEsc* plugin. Note that the fork had its last change one year ago, but the original is still being maintained (with development versions published on [DrChip's private website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#ANSIESC)), with the last update on Apr-2018.

That script's functionality needs to be explicitly enabled for a buffer, via the `:AnsiEsc` command. If you've run `:helptags`, you should also have its full documentation at `:help AnsiEsc`.